# Redactee and Safecracker

Tags: safecracker, redactor

I’ve a redactee’s channel field named “messaggio” and this is my code inside the safecracker form

```
<label>Scrivi la tua richiesta*</label>
{field:messaggio}
```

But the result is only a simple textarea and not Redactee
How can i resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: I'd start by checking if you have any JS errors in Chrome or Firebug consoles. I don't see where they host their docs so, not positive your syntax is correct or not and I don't currently have a copy, sorry.

Comment: This is the error in the chrome console http://d.pr/i/FzXP

Comment: That's a bug in core if I remember right. I'd do a search for it over in the bug tracker. Specifically the markItUP part.

Comment: resolved: "Note: If you are using your own copy of jQuery you will need to load it before the SafeCracker form."

Comment: Francesco, please add the answer yourself with as much description as possible to help others solve this issue in the future. Then mark your own answer as the "best" answer :)

Comment: Done, i can mark my answer tomorrow. Thanks Natetronn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery library must be loaded BEFORE the safecracker form (in the head of your page)

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#include-jquery